# Is it possible upload the file in other project directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a solution file that consist of two different projects.
In one of the projects i have a code to upload the file and save it.

Currently the file is saved in same project directory that consist of code to upload the file.

I want to upload the file in other project directory.

Is it possible.

I am developing the application in asp.net mvc.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Just change the the destination path.

Comment: Thanks to reply,

but my question is upload the file in other project directory from other project.